# Audio not playing smoothly by using MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, audio

I've used the following code.
Audio is being played but is not smooth.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sample);
        mediaPlayer.start();
     }
```

Comment: Code posted is very simple, I guess if playback is not smooth then probably the device capabilities to reproduce the specific sound sample are limited.

Comment: There is no problem with the device capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mediaplayer on different thread rather then UI thread. It will play smooth then.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `OnPreparedListener` and start playback in the `onPrepared` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sample);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
 }
```

Comment: mediaPlayer.prepare() throwing an IOException and when handled causing an IllegalStateException

Comment: it is still not smooth

Comment: Ok so update your question and include this sound sample so that others can replicate this “not smooth” behavior.

Comment: used prepareAsync() instead of prepare(). Its working fine now. :)